# logstash to webhdfs Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, logstash, webhdfs

I try to ingest csv file vrom filebeat into hdfs by logstash.
Filebeat successfully transferred it to logstash because im using stdout{codec=>rubydebug} and i can see the them being parsed.Seems like problem started when inside webhdfs module.

### logstash-sample.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
output {
        stdout{
                codec=>rubydebug
        }
        webhdfs{
                host=>"x.x.x.x"
                port => 50070
                path => "/user/logstash/df=%{+YYY-MM-dd}/logstash-%{+HH}.log"
                user => "root"
        }
}
```

### error

```
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:27.437 [[main]>worker0] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"RecoveryInProgressException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.RecoveryInProgressException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_412561106_43 on 10.64.2.236 because lease recovery is in progress. Try again later.\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2591)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:27.465 [[main]>worker0] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"RecoveryInProgressException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.RecoveryInProgressException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-352502454_44 on 10.64.2.236 because another recovery is in progress by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-601230909_43 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2599)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:27.984 [[main]>worker0] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"RecoveryInProgressException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.RecoveryInProgressException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_557749444_45 on 10.64.2.236 because another recovery is in progress by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-601230909_43 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2599)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:29.010 [[main]>worker0] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"RecoveryInProgressException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.RecoveryInProgressException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1871050100_46 on 10.64.2.236 because another recovery is in progress by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-601230909_43 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2599)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:30.547 [[main]>worker0] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"IOException","javaClassName":"java.io.IOException","message":"Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.64.2.236:50010,DS-99ecf21e-ad4a-41f0-a3ae-7d430e2f5ea0,DISK]], original=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.64.2.236:50010,DS-99ecf21e-ad4a-41f0-a3ae-7d430e2f5ea0,DISK]]). The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration."}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[ERROR] 2020-06-25 11:43:32.570 [[main]>worker0] webhdfs - Max write retries reached. Events will be discarded. Exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AlreadyBeingCreatedException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_2073135911_40 on 10.64.2.236 because this file lease is currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1387502348_39 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:33.528 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AlreadyBeingCreatedException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1033064335_41 on 10.64.2.236 because this file lease is currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1387502348_39 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:33.556 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AlreadyBeingCreatedException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1192450546_42 on 10.64.2.236 because this file lease is currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1387502348_39 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:34.077 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AlreadyBeingCreatedException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-405184820_43 on 10.64.2.236 because this file lease is currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1387502348_39 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:35.099 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AlreadyBeingCreatedException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_2036955244_44 on 10.64.2.236 because this file lease is currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1387502348_39 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[WARN ] 2020-06-25 11:43:36.621 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] webhdfs - webhdfs write caused an exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AlreadyBeingCreatedException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_245206024_45 on 10.64.2.236 because this file lease is currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1387502348_39 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}. Maybe you should increase retry_interval or reduce number of workers. Retrying...
[ERROR] 2020-06-25 11:43:38.653 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] webhdfs - Max write retries reached. Events will be discarded. Exception: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AlreadyBeingCreatedException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException","message":"Failed to APPEND_FILE /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_331276113_46 on 10.64.2.236 because this file lease is currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1387502348_39 on 10.64.2.236\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAppendOp.appendFile(FSDirAppendOp.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2639)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)\n"}}
```

## EDIT

I've changed logstash folder into accessible by user as `hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/logstash`
this only change the exist folder, but everytime i run logstash it will generate new file which that unaccessible as

```
root@ambari:/etc/logstash/conf.d# hdfs dfs -ls /user/logstash
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - root hdfs          0 2020-06-25 13:23 /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25
root@ambari:/etc/logstash/conf.d# hdfs dfs -ls /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25
Found 2 items
-rwxrwxrwx   3 root hdfs         63 2020-06-25 12:43 /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-11.log
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs         63 2020-06-25 13:23 /user/logstash/df=2020-06-25/logstash-13.log
```

the latest one is 13

## EDIT2

i've change owner into logstash

```
root@ambari:/etc/logstash# sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chown -R logstash /user/logstash
root@ambari:/etc/logstash# hdfs dfs -ls /user
Found 6 items
drwxrwx---   - ambari-qa hdfs          0 2020-05-28 03:08 /user/ambari-qa
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop    hdfs          0 2020-06-25 11:21 /user/hadoop
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs      hdfs          0 2020-06-02 05:08 /user/hdfs
drwxrwxrwx   - logstash  hdfs          0 2020-06-26 07:23 /user/logstash
drwxrwxrwx   - root      hdfs          0 2020-06-26 09:53 /user/root
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs      hdfs          0 2020-06-02 04:48 /user/sample
```

but when i run  it, it still returning the same error log

## question

1. Even if i `chown` `/user/logstash` they will keep on generating file which is unaccessable for current user, what should i do so user can append/access the file? Thank you so much

Comment: You definitely need to give correct permissions to the hdfs folder, and execute with correct user, not root.      It looks like it may be trying to write each line,  not append..

Comment: Dear Steven, Thank you so much for your respond. I've set user/logstash with ``hadop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/logstash`` and i've i decided to change dfs.permissions.enabled into false (default is true) and rerun. Still no luck. Any other suggestons please?

Comment: how do we create permission so that everytime hdfs creating file it will be accessible?

Comment: or if you do what you actually mean, can you tell me how? i mean i'm new in hadoop and linux  environment too. thank you

Comment: @steven-dfheinz who else is the user? I mean is there any other user other than me/root/hdfs?

Comment: The logstash user....  if the file is owned to root, logstash won’t be able to write to file....  chown the folder to logstash:hdfs, run as logstash and files should be logstash:hdfs

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your sugestion, i've changed the file owner into logstash, but the error still there. @steven-dfheinz

Comment: make sure the logstash conf is logstash user too...  just to make everything consistent...   I created an answer with hopefully some information that helps you get your issue resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Yuliansen.  Your process is appending files across hdfs data nodes.  I was able to find some relevant info on the internet searching for "hdfs Max write retries reached. Events will be discarded."

> Locked file leases are a known issue when appending with multiple
> threads to the same file via webhdfs.
>
> With my research and tryouts, it turned out that if the replication
> factor for HDFS is greater than the number of datanodes available,
> append would fail to write as it needs to take care of multiple
> copies. Try setting a low replica factor for the log file.

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-webhdfs/issues/15

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-webhdfs/issues/35

There is a patch in a link above, as well as some additional suggestions for adjusting HDFS workers, replicas, and configs.   In hadoop it is important to research the entire output in the error statements.  They are very long and very far to the right to find the messages.

Comment: Amazing explanation and effort, thank you so much. I'm using ambari on my HDP and according to this source ``https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Unable-to-change-the-replication-factor-from-3-to-2/m-p/218972#M180873``, i dont have ``dfs.replication`` settings anywhere on hdfs advanced config ``http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml``. Or maybe if i  have to edit it  manually in ``hdfs-site.xml`` is it safe for my environment since I have everything under ambari. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: from ambari advanced just search "replica"... you should find a match in there for sure...  also check out how many data nodes you have, maybe you dont have enough for replicas....

Comment: Amazingly done!!! I said i didnt find it because it was on a different label, instead of ``dfs.replication`` it was in ``Block replication``. They all ingested well. Problem is, data was ingested not in the right order. I think i will research on that. Problem solved, thank you so much.